# React.js see tab name only after tab is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my React.js project I am using react-helmet to manage tab names. Also I got a table with different page names. When I right click on those pages and open them in a new tab, I cannot see tab name until tab is clicked (see the pic below). So I need to see tab names right after right click and `open in a new tab` menu. Could anyone advice what is the reason for this and how this can be fixed? Thank you.

[image: tabs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helmet internally uses `requestAnimationFrame` which doesn't run for background tabs, so unless you focus on the tab the title won't change

However helmet provides a `defer` prop which if you set to false, the requestAnimationFrame will be skipped

use it like

```
<Helmer defer={false}>
    {/* Your data */}
</Helmet>
```

[Linked github issue](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/315)